# Can you use a photon's torque to change a molecule?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure

Can you use the torque of a photon to change bond angles, etc.? 11-Cis-Retinal to the all trans version, in  the eye, is a good illustration [[1](https://doi.org/10/gf4f6h)].

Note: This phenomenon can be observed by closing blinds, allowing the sun to shine through, you get light beams. If you blow a smoky material past it, you can observe this phenomenon of light.

#### References

1. Rego, L.; Dorney, K. M.; Brooks, N. J.; Nguyen, Q. L.; Liao, C.-T.; Román, J. S.; Couch, D. E.; Liu, A.; Pisanty, E.; Lewenstein, M.; et al. Generation of Extreme-Ultraviolet Beams with Time-Varying Orbital Angular Momentum. *Science* **2019**, 364 (6447), eaaw9486. https://doi.org/10/gf4f6h.

Comment: Molecules are solid, they don't change. Except the rare cases when they do. Can you change a piece of metal with your bare hand?  Normally no, but sometimes yes. Same thing here.

Comment: Probably not, normally the total energy of a photon is needed to produce an excited state, (by being absorbed by the molecule), and from which isomerisation/bond breaking  can occur. This is the case in your example where 2 to 3 eV are needed, and the torque is not likely to be of sufficient energy. You should ask a question in Physics StackExchange to better understand what this torque actually is, as opposed to circular polarisation, for example.

Comment: Hey Ivan, thanks for the information!

Comment: Porphyrin- I am not trying to get the photon to be absorbed by an electron. I am wondering if bombarding a specific bond with photons with torque could change the orientation of a bond. i only provided the study to give more information. Thank you! Just trying to figure things out.

Comment: What makes you think that the reference you've provided is relevant to 11-Cis-Retinal?

Comment: The torque could be used to align whole molecules, see the info at CFEL in Hamburg https://www.controlled-molecule-imaging.org/, and corkscrew -laser technique

Comment: @porphyrin At technique uses optical *spin* angular momentum (which is tied to the polarization), not the orbital angular momentum (tied to the spatial dependence) which is at play in the referenced publication, i.e. the two have very little to do with each other. They're similar, but they operate at vastly different length scales - OAM will only couple to objects at the size of the wavelength.

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty Thanks for clarification.

Comment: Hey Guys, i only added the study to show photons can have a torque associated with them. That is really all. The same answer basically for the question about 11-cis-retinal. I only included it to give an example. Thanks guys!

Comment: What relevance does this have to *spin*?? "This phenomenon can be observed by closing blinds, allowing the sun to shine through, you get light beams. If you blow a smoky material past it, you can observe this phenomenon of light."

Comment: I think it is cool to observe natural phenomena that surrounds us. I would say with 95% confidence that the beam of light created by the method i described has photons with a torque. I think it confirms the experiment i linked to since you can actually see the phenomena as the study i linked originally mentioned states when interacting with matter. I can literally see the movement.
https://www.nature.com/news/people-can-sense-single-photons-1.20282

Comment: @kevindelahoussaye If your core question is whether optical forces are sufficient to directly twist a molecule, then your reference acts in a way to make it directly harder for your question to be answered. (This is because the reference you provided is highly suboptimal to addressing molecular structures compared to e.g. optical centrifuges.) If you're asking about the applicability of that specific paper to twisting molecules, then ask explicitly. (Full disclosure - I'm an author in the reference you cited.)

Comment: Hey Emilio, Thanks for the response! As mentioned above the only reason i included your paper was to show photons can have a torque. I believe your paper does that. I am not asking about the applicability of your paper to twisting molecules; only to show they have a torque. Which i then wondered if you could use the torque on photons, that exist in plenty in the world, to change a bond. I do not know of any techniques to produce photons with a certain torque. That is also another reason. I think it is probable that photons can change orientation given it seems to happen in our bodies. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry if my reference skills are not up to par. I was not even aware of optical centrifuges. Thank you for your contribution! Please pass along my warmest regards.